# Regex for 3 required groups in any order

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a single line of text, and I'm trying to split up the notes a user entered which has 3 required parts - a note of any length and content, a date of known formatting, and the user's 2-4 letter initials.  All parts are required, but I have found that in the notes I'm parsing, users have regularly entered all 6 possible orderings:

> 1/1/21 PB This is a note
> PB 1/1/21 This is a note
> PB This is a note 1/1/21
> 1/1/21 This is a note PB
> This is a note 1/1/21 PB
> This is a note PB 1/1/21

As I am using .NET, I'm used named capture groups to make my life easy, so the regexes for the 3 parts are below.  The  regex is long due to some industry-specific notation; suffice to say the regex for this group is written and works well.

```
(?<note>.*?)
(?<initials>[A-Z]{2,4})
(?<date>TBD)
```

Users also always put some kind of visual separator character between the parts, like the space I used above; `[ :-]+` covers all the cases I've found.  A regex for the first bullet above would look like:

```
^\w*(?<date>TBD)[ :-]+(?<initials>[A-Z]{2,4})[ :-]+(?<note>.*?)\w*$
```

The separator chars are intentionally dropped from the capture groups.

So how would I go about writing this such that each of the 3 required pieces are matched but in any order and not repeated?  I believe either conditional groups or lookaround is the solution, but I'm having a lot of trouble figuring how to arrive at anything that works.

*Also, as a bonus headache,* I have noticed that notes like the following cause problems:

> DO NOT RENEW - KF 4/1/22

My regex above doesn't know if "DO NOT RENEW" is the note and "KF" is the initials or if "NOT RENEW - KF" is the note and "DO" is the initials.  As humans we see the `-` separator and know which option is correct.  So it would be amazing if, in an ambiguous situation, prefer the match which has a non-whitespace separator char.

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can reuse the named capture groups and use an alteration to match all forms.

For example matching the first 3 lines:

```
^(?:(?<date>\d+/\d+/\d+)[ :-]+(?<initials>[A-Z]{2,4})[ :-]+(?<note>.*)|(?<initials>[A-Z]{2,4})[ :-]+(?<date>\d+/\d+/\d+)[ :-]+(?<note>.*)|(?<initials>[A-Z]{2,4})[ :-]+(?<note>.*?)[ :-]+(?<date>\d+/\d+/\d+))$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mqTMNg/1).

Comment: Thx.  So this is a brute-force solution where the regex just has all 6 possible orderings listed as alternations?  I just want to be sure I understand it.

Comment: @pbarranis Yes, that is correct.

Comment: These kinds of brute-force solutions really bother me, but in regexes they often seem unavoidable (i.e. certainly not the fault of the answer or answerer).  I could use MoreLINQ's Premutations function to construct it at run-time so the code is a bit more maintainable I guess.  That said, is there a regex-based solution to my other problem - preferring a match that has non-whitespace separators to one that doesn't?  (Doing it with code is of course possible but seems ugly off-hand.)

Comment: TIA.  My default way of solving problems is with code algorithms (C#) not regexes.  By trying to find regex-based solutions to things, I'm trying to expand past my rookie-level regex knowledge.